# Multi-Level Dropdowns menu item

Tags: jquery, css

How to update this code to hide menu items when focus lost.
After you make the selection and click again on tutorials button all menu item still open.

Please try.

Working example:
https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_js_dropdown_multilevel_css&stacked=h

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    .dropdown-submenu {
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
        top: 0;
        left: 100%;
        margin-top: -1px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Multi-Level Dropdowns</h2>
      <p>In this example, we have created a .dropdown-submenu class for multi-level dropdowns (see style section above).</p>
      <p>Note that we have added jQuery to open the multi-level dropdown on click (see script section below).</p>                                        
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Tutorials
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">HTML</a></li>
          <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">CSS</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="test" tabindex="-1" href="#">New dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
              <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">2nd level dropdown</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a class="test" href="#">Another dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">3rd level dropdown</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){
        $(this).next('ul').toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    });
    </script>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the toggle with 2 different functions which show and hide the ul's. Then you can add code in the hide function where you hide all the children ul's.

Something like this could help you perhaps:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-submenu a.test').on("click", function(e){

    if ( $(this).next('ul').is(":visible") ) {
      $(this).children().hide();
    } else {
      $(this).next('ul').show();
    }

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Note: I haven't tested this yet, so my code may contain errors, I only wish to show you what I'm thinking of.